# Even if electromagnetic zero point energy existed wouldn't it be exactly zero due to both positive and negative em potentials canceled out?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

The way you get the walue of zero point energy density in some patch of space is by integrating through all the frequency modes of the quantum em field, possibly up to some cutoff frequency.
 It turns out to be a very large number and is one of the greatest problems in physics why it is many orders of magnitude bigger than the density of vacuum predicted by the lambda cdm model.of cosmology

But why is there em zero point energy when there are two opposite charges?

Comment: There are no charges involved in the zpe paradox.

Comment: Even in classical electromagnetism the energy density of an electrostatic field is proportional to $\mathbf{E}^2$ and thus positive for either a positive charge or a negative charge.